# What does embedding do in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am reading an example of using RNN with tensorflow here: [ptb_word_lm.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py)

I can't figure out what the `embedding` and `embedding_lookup` are doing here.  How can it add another dimension to the tensor?  Going from (20, 25) to (20, 25, 200).  In this case (20,25) is a batch-size of 20 with 25 time steps.  I can't understand how/why you can add the `hidden_size` of the cell as a dimension of the input data?  Typically the input data would be a matrix of size `[batch_size, num_features]` and the model would map `num_features` ---> `hidden_dims` with a matrix of size `[num_features, hidden_dims]` yielding an output of size `[batch-size, hidden-dims]`.  So how can `hidden_dims` be a dimension of the input tensor?

```
input_data, targets = reader.ptb_producer(train_data, 20, 25)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(200, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
initial_state = cell.zero_state(20, tf.float32)
embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [10000, 200], dtype=tf.float32)
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_data)

input_data_train # <tf.Tensor 'PTBProducer/Slice:0' shape=(20, 25) dtype=int32>
inputs # <tf.Tensor 'embedding_lookup:0' shape=(20, 25, 200) dtype=float32>

outputs = []
state = initial_state
for time_step in range(25):
    if time_step > 0: 
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

    cell_output, state = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)

output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, 200])

outputs # list of 20: <tf.Tensor 'BasicLSTMCell/mul_2:0' shape=(20, 200) dtype=float32>
output # <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_2:0' shape=(500, 200) dtype=float32>

softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [config.hidden_size, config.vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)
softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [config.hidden_size, config.vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b

loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits], [tf.reshape(targets, [-1])],[tf.ones([20*25], dtype=tf.float32)])
cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
```

Answer (score 14):

ok, I'm not going to try and explain this specific code, but I will try and answer the "what is an embedding?" part of the title.

Basically it's a mapping of the original input data into some  set of real-valued dimensions, and the "position" of the original input data in those dimensions is organized to improve the task.

In tensorflow, if you imagine some text input field has "king", "queen", "girl","boy",  and you have 2 embedding dimensions. Hopefully the backprop will train the embedding to put the concept of royalty on one axis and gender on the other. So in this case, what was a 4 categorical value feature gets "boiled" down to a floating point embedding feature with 2 dimensions.

They are implemented using a lookup table, either hashed from the original or from a dictionary ordering. For a fully trained one, You might put in "Queen", and you get out say [1.0,1.0], Put in "Boy" and you get out [0.0,0.0].

Tensorflow does backprop of the error INTO this lookup table, and hopefully what starts off as a randomly initialized dictionary will gradually become like we see above.

Hope this helps. If not, look at: http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/

Answer (score 2):

At simplest,

`input_data`: Batch of sequence of word IDs (with shape (20,25))

`inputs`: Batch of sequence of word embeddings (with shape (20,25,200))

How does `input_data` becomes `inputs` you might ask? This is what **learning word embeddings** does. The easiest way to imagine is,

1. unwrap the `input_data` to a single batch of shape `(20*25,)`.
2. Now assign a vector of size `200` for each element in that unwrapped `input_data` which gives you a matrix of shape `(20*25,200)`.
3. Now, reshape the matrix to shape `(20,25,200)`.

This is because, embedding learning is not a time-series process. You learn word embeddings with a feed forward network. Next important question would be, how do you learn the word embeddings.

1. Initialise a huge Tensorflow variable of size `(vocabulary_size, 200)` (i.e. `embedding` in the code)
2. Optimise the `embedding` so that a given word should be able to predict any word from its context. (e.g. in "dog barked at the mailman", if "at" is the target word "dog", "barked", "the" and "mailman" are context words)
3. This process give you a vector (`200` long in this example) for each word, such that semantics are preserved (i.e. vector of "dog" is close to "cat", but far away from "pen").

Here's an overview of what I just explained.

[image: Image:embeddings]